# UIView animation prevents touch events?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uianimation, touch-event

On Objective-C when animation starts on the UIView, no touch interaction is accepted. how can we handle this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction as an option parameter in method animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:

[UIViewAnimationOptions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIViewAnimationOptions)